# Does Spring refresh token in default implementation of Spring OAuth2

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to add OAuth provider other than common ones (google, facebook). 
I'm wondering if Spring default implementation in callback **{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}** automatically refresh access token and if there is a way to override the request for access token from refresh token (refresh token grant).

Here's what I have customized in security filter chain:

- authorizationEndpoint
- tokenEndpoint
- userInfoEndpoint

Thank you for reading